# Repackaging DVD TV Episodes

Tags: dvd, handbrake

So I have a load of DVDs of episodes that are on my harddrive in the normal DVD format (VOB).

I'd like to repackage these into the individual episodes in a way such that it is lossless.

I know I can use handbrake and can select the individual titles which relate the the episodes but:

1. Which settings do I select for lossless? - I was expecting to play the movies on my android device using something like VLC player, which should be fine with MPEG-2, even if the filesize is fine. What am I slightly worried about is the bitrate and my WIFI connection, will it be enough? The reason I do not want to encode is that I will be doing this on an atom machine which has no CPU.
2. Is there any way I can do this automatically, without having to open the gui and select the individual titles for each DVD (there are 100s!)

Comment: Converting losslessly will, in most cases, just make a file as big as the DVD itself. Assuming you used H.264 you can push the Quality slider to 0.
You can do that automatically (or so I think) by allowing Handbrake to scan a folder where you have those DVD's.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment, converting video (regardless of source) to lossless will give you a file that is as heavy as the original file. I'm not the one saying it, its **Handbrake** itself.

[image: Handbrake Tooltip]

And as Handbrake says, FFmpeg doesn't have a lossless mode, so trying to convert your DVD's to MPEG-2 will result in some loss of information.

Now, how much information will you lose?

I actually convert a lot of videos to my old [Nokia 5230](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_5230). Since the final resolution is roughly `640 x 360` even at normal (by Handbrake's defaults) quality settings the video files come out relatively good. And small, which is a plus.

Consider that a DVD might display an hour of video in about 1 to 2 GB, the same can be done by re-encoding the file in H.264 or MPEG-4 in about 150-200 Mb. That's a 90% saving (the numbers will eventually vary baring on the complexity of the image, but real cases aren't going to veer off this mark)

My Nokia has a processor that runs at about `434 MHz`. Most newer smartphones have processor speeds nearing or topping the `1 GHz` mark. Take for instance [Samsung Galaxy S4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4), a smartphone that runs Android, has quad-core `1.6 GHz` processor and Full HD `(1920 x 1080)` resolution. With that setup you have two things:

1. The resolution of the DVD's is far lower (about 3 to 4 times) than HD. So, the phone is not going to have problems.
2. Since the resolution is lower and processing speed is higher, again you won't run into problems.

However i'm somewhat confused as to your last phrase, so I'm asking you to clarify that so that I can give you a good answer. Quoting:

> What am I slightly worried about is the bitrate and my WIFI connection, will it be enough? The reason I do not want to encode is that I will be doing this on an atom machine which has no CPU.

As I can see, you're asking about streaming. But without knowing your WiFi or your machine we/I can't give you a good answer. However, it is, from my point of view, more sane to re-encode the DVD's as you will get a decrease in bitrate with the added benefit of retaining most visual information.

[image: Handbrake file menu]

As for the 2nd point, Handbrake has a functionality that allows to scan for video files (for reference it is the **Folder** buttons). The files are then loaded into Handbrake. You would have to set each file (since Handbrake doesn't expect each file to have exactly the same configuration, take subtitles or audio tracks for instance), but since the encoding process and the pre-processing process are independent, even with 100 DVD files you won't spend a lot of time. You can make a preset to ease your time.

(I haven't personally tried to convert DVD's but I assume the process is roughly the same it is for regular files)

Handbrake has also command-line features, that can be looked up in their support pages.